# Independent variable as a percent in a binary logistic regression

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, binary-data

I understand the basics of binary logistic regression when the independent variable is a dichotomous variable.  However, I am working with a dataset that has the dependent as a dichotomous variable and my independent variable is a percentage.  So for example I am looking at how the percent change in revenue from the previous year impacts the probability of a particular policy being implemented.  The independent variable is in the .10 (10%) form.

My question is how do I interpret the odds ratio?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"A one percentage point higher change of revenue from the previous year is associated with a *beta* increase in the odds ratio."